# Update startRobot method so it can now cater for an arrayList of robots

Tags: java, arraylist

I have the following class:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tester04 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EntertainmentRobot eRob = new EntertainmentRobot("QRIO", 7.3, 0.6, "SONY");
        HumanStudyRobot rob = new HumanStudyRobot("HRP", 1.5, 58.0, "Kawada Industries");

        ArrayList<Robot> list = new ArrayList<Robot>();
        list.add(eRob);
        list.add(rob);

        eRob.setPurpose("To live with you, make life fun and make you happy");
        rob.setPurpose("Study into human movement and perform a wide range of tasks");
        System.out.print(list.get(0) + "\n" + list.get(1));

    }

    public static void startRobot(Robot robot, Scanner input) {
        robot.doTask(input);
        robot.doTask();
    }
}
```

As you can see I have set up an `ArrayList` of robots. I am now trying to update my startRobot method to cater for such an arrayList and I'm unsure how to proceed. Any input would be appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Can you clarify that exactly are you want to do?

Exec `doTask()` for each robot like this:

```
public static void startRobot(ArrayList<Robot> robots, Scanner input) {
    robots.parallelStream().forEach(Robot::doTask);
}
```

using `Java 8` features such as `Stream API` and `Method references`